# Python cannot find module when run as another user

Tags: drivers, permissions, python

i have run into the problem with running python as another user. I have checked the other posts but seems like my problem is a bit different as solutions don't work.
I am logging as 'yuri' and start ClickHouse as 'clickhouse' user.
I want to run UDF in ClickHouse, so it is similar as running a python program as a 'clickhouse' user. Here I ran into the issues with finding python modules.
So far i have tried the following:

1. when running as sudo -u 'yuri' all works:

   ```
   $ sudo  -u 'yuri'  /usr/bin/python3 -c "import sys; sys.path = ['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/yuri/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages']; print(sys.path);import sentence_transformers; print('done')"

   ['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/yuri/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages']
   done
   ```

2. when running as sudo -u 'clickhouse' doesn't find the module despite defining sys.path:

   ```
   sudo  -u 'clickhouse'  /usr/bin/python3 -c "import sys; sys.path = ['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/yuri/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages']; print(sys.path);import sentence_transformers; print('done')"

   ['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/yuri/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages']
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sentence_transformers'
   ```

I have set permissions to the directory (recursively) with modules to 777, also even changed the owner to 'clickhouse':

```
~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages$ ls -ld */

drwxrwxrwx  9 clickhouse yuri 4096 Oct 13 16:01 sentence_transformers/

drwxrwxrwx  2 clickhouse yuri 4096 Oct 13 16:01 sentence_transformers-2.2.2.dist-info/
```

At this stage I am really lost, what else should I do?
'clickhouse' user is created when I run the program, not a proper user.

```
$ groups clickhouse

clickhouse : clickhouse
```

Thanks

Comment: Simply install all necessary module for the designated user using pip.

Comment: The problem in this case the size of the required modules is 5GB so would rather avoid duplication.

Comment: The other option is to install them system-wide. Which is not recommended and may be prevented by pip, depending on which version you are running.